# How to define local user in mysql database without entering a password?

Tags: mysql

How would create another user in my mysql database so another person who is working on my rails application can also get access to the server?

Most articles I found on the question tell me to type in a command like "mysql --user=root mysql -p" that requires a password (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/adding-users.html)

Is there anyway around this?

Comment: When you say _without a password_ you mean without logging into MySQL using a password, to create the user, or creating a user in MySQL that does not need password to log into the database?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply create an user without giving a password.

```
create user 'xxx'@'localhost'
```